# Yet another C++ list question

Tags: c++, list, loops

Im quite stuck here and I have tried my best but I could not solve it.

I would like to do this:

```
list<Enemy> *_myEnemies;
Enemy* _myEnemiesPushBack;

_myEnemiesPushBack = new Enemy;
_myEnemiesPushBack->load("earth.png");
_myEnemiesPushBack->setPos(150, 150);
_myEnemies->push_back(_myEnemiesPushBack); //error here
```

The error:

> \init.cpp(41): error C2664: 'void
>   std::list<_Ty>::push_back(_Ty &&)' :
>   cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Enemy
>   *' to 'Enemy &&' 1>          with 1>          [ 1>              _Ty=Enemy 1>
>   ] 1>          Reason: cannot convert
>   from 'Enemy *' to 'Enemy' 1>
>   No constructor could take the source
>   type, or constructor overload
>   resolution was ambiguous

Thanks!

Comment: You have a pointer-to-Enemy list, not a list of pointer-to-Enemy.

Comment: don't you mean pointer to Enemy-list? As I read it, "pointer-to-Enemy list" means the same thing as "list of pointer-to-Enemy". ;)

Comment: Please don't use pointers like this, use a smart pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need pointers, at all.

```
std::list<Enemy> myList;

Enemy en;
en.load("earth.png");
en.setPos(150,150);
myList.push_back(en);

typedef std::list<Enemy>::iterator iterator;
for (iterator it = list.begin(), end = list.end(); it != end; ++it) {
  it->move();
}
```

I would also encourage you to fetch a book about C++ somewhere (for beginners), or about the STL if it's your particular hurdle. C++ is not, unfortunately, something you can experiment with without guidance (at first at least).

Comment: Got it. Multiple enemies on screen now! Wohoo! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You misplaced a `*`

```
list<Enemy*> _myEnemies;
Enemy* _myEnemiesPushBack;

_myEnemiesPushBack = new Enemy;
_myEnemiesPushBack->load("earth.png");
_myEnemiesPushBack->setPos(150, 150);
_myEnemies.push_back(_myEnemiesPushBack); //error here
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! I really sat for hours trying to solve it.

Comment: Sorry, One last question. How would I make an iterator? I made it like this list<Enemy*>::iterator it; but it gives me error upon it->move();

Comment: @Jesper, I think it is `(*it)->move();`

Answer (score 0):

You've got a list of Enemy's and are trying to push a pointer to an Enemy into that list.  They're not the same type.

Take a look here:
[Pointers @ cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/418/)

Comment: You mean: he has a **pointer** to a list of enemies. But he should need a list of **pointers** to enemies.

Comment: Alf's book is better for pointers imo : https://docs.google.com/fileview?id=0B2oiI2reHOh4M2MzNzYwYzQtMGZkNC00NTljLWJiM2UtOGI0MmRkMTMyZGY4&pli=1

Comment: Thanks for the link Muggen :)